# Pegando dados do checkbox e enviando para o banco

Tags: banco-de-dados, checkbox, laravel-5

Estou criando um formulario e preciso enviar para o banco os checkbox selecionados. Tenho a tabela `conta`, `conta_categoria` e `categoria`. Na `conta_categoria` tenho o `id_conta` e o `id_categoria`.

Como eu enviaria todos os dados dos **checkbox selecionados** pra tabela `conta_categoria`?

Meu form create.blade

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('descricao', 'Categoria: ') !!}
    @foreach (Realito\Categoria::all() as $categoria)
        <br>
        {!! Form::checkbox('descricao[]',$categoria->id_categoria) !!}
        {{ $categoria->id    }}
        {{ $categoria->descricao }}
        </br>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Meu controller de conta onde ta inserindo os dados

if($conta->save()){

```
      $contasCategoria = new \App\ContasCategoria();

      $contasCategoria->id_conta = $ultimoID;

      $contasCategoria->id_categoria = $request->get('categoria[]');
        // $contasCategoria->id_categoria = $codCategoria;
      $conta->contasCategoria()->save($contasCategoria);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você trocar o nome do checkbox para descricao[], desta forma:

```
{!! Form::checkbox('descricao[]',$categoria->id_categoria) !!}
```

No seu controller, você irá receber um array só com as categorias selecionadas.
Tipo assim `$request->get('descricao') = Array([0] => 100, [1] => 103, [2] => 105);`
Neste caso você pode fazer um foreach ou então criar um método para salvar varias categorias de uma vez.

Ve se assim resolve para gravar as categorias.

```
$categorias = $request->get('categoria[]');
foreach($categorias as $categoria){
      $contasCategoria = new \App\ContasCategoria();

      $contasCategoria->id_conta = $ultimoID;

      $contasCategoria->id_categoria = $categoria;
      $conta->contasCategoria()->save($contasCategoria);
}
```

Comment: Bom.. não consegui fzr exatamente como vc falou ainda to com duvida.. até fiz salvar no banco quando seleciona um só.. mas não com o array. nao acertei fazer o foreach para adicionar os arrays 
 
  if($conta->save()){

         $contasCategoria = new \Realito\ContasCategoria();

         $contasCategoria->id_conta = $ultimoID;

         $contasCategoria->id_categoria = $request->get('categoria');

         $conta->contasCategoria()->save($contasCategoria);


    }

Comment: atualiza sua pergunta com o código atual.

Comment: Pronto... dando dd($request) ele me retorna os campos selecionads

Comment: na viu você vai nomear o campo de 'descricao[]' (com o colchete). Mas na controller você vai utilizar $request->get('categoria'); (sem colchete).

Comment: Faz o seguinte, da um dd($request->get('categoria'));

Comment: fiz isso e ele me trouxe as 4 categorias selecionadas, só falta enviar as 4 para o banco

Comment: é só você fazer um for ou foreach agora, salvando um por um.

Comment: esse foreach que não estou acertando fazer..

Comment: da uma olhada, adicionei o código na minha resposta. Ve se assim resolve.

Comment: obrigado euler. tinha acabado de resolver ia fechar topico. Mas mt obrigado pela ajuda.. foi de grande serventia!

Comment: De nada amigo. Um abraço.